# Run command every second but must wait done execute

Tags: c#, loops, timer

i wanna run loop when program running,
but when it run loop, inside loop, have some code to execute,
what i want is, loop after it execute code inside the loop and it will delay 500 milliseconds.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
myTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 ms is one second
myTimer.Start();

public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // code here will run every second
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rnd2 = rnd.Next(500,2000);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd2);
}
```

So, the loop doing after execute code inside.

Comment: what is the error you face now

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: are you asking for help in fixing your code?

Comment: @utility no fixing code, but just questing about this timer function (like that),,,,  because i try it,,,,, if you run code inside DisplayTimeEvent, it doesn't care how long you run your code inside, it keep loop every (1) second (it will make it multi process code inside DisplayTimeEvent),,,,,, what i want is, it run after it run code inside ant continue loop,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question, you are looking for a way to stop the timer once you start the `DisplayTimeEvent` method and restart if once it's done.
Though it's not clear from your question if you are using [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Timer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Timers.Timer(v=vs.110).aspx), they both have a `Stop()` method you can use:

```
public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
myTimer.Stop();
// your code goes here
myTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: yes, something like this,
it is will harm or something like that
if i put it on windows services????

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no. Stopping and starting a timer can't cause any harm,

Comment: and i'm 'using System.Timers'

Comment: Does this fully answers your question? if so, you should accept the answer . Do not accept it unless it really solves your problem.